# auto-sync directory on two linux machines over SSH

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a root folder on two computers (that I run programs on alternately). Let's say:

```
server0:
  -my_dir
    --subdir0
    --subdir1
server1:
  -my_dir
    --subdir0
    --subdir1
```

So I have batch jobs on server0 that will update some files in these dirs. And I have interactive jobs on server1 which will also update these files. It's guaranteed that I'll never update the same file at the same time.

I have access from server1 to server0 through SSH.

I've checked out solutions that's supposed to do this. osync and unison all seem to be doing this. But they're all only triggered from 1 machine. So file updates on server0, for example, won't trigger an update. Only updates on server1.

I

The same issue exists with rsync. If rsync runs on both servers, it's very possible to get race conditions where the 2 servers bounce the same files back and forth.

Anyone know of a solution for this?

Comment: Why not have the directories only exist on 1 server and use NFS or some such to share it (sshfs at a push). Then you can backup over rsync to another path just-on-case. There are also block level solutions worth looking at, but these come with complexity and performance penalties. I'm thinking drbd/Mars/moosefs... Another approach could be to use something like GIT.

Comment: The issue is I want it to be automatic and transparent. Literally mirror one directory on two computers (as I launch tools that manipulate data on both computers).

Answer (score 1):

One solution consists of running inotifywait on each server which will detect newly exisisting files on **my_dir**  then once a new file is created it will use rsync to copy the file to the other server with ignoring it if the file already exists on the destination, here is a basic idea :

From **server0** point of view :

```
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "{my_dir}" | while read NEWFILE
do    
rsync --ignore-existing "$NEWFILE" "$server1":"$my_dir"
done
```